# How much traffic isn't reported by Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, statistics, awstats

We keep finding inconsistencies between data in Analytics and the reports we get from other sources. In general, we notice about 40% less pageviews in Analytics than elsewhere:

- Correlating number of new accounts and number of views of the registration page.
- Comparing the pageviews on a subset of static page with the AWstats reports.
- Goals in our Analytics and reports from a partner tracking incoming links.

The differences are not negligible. More than 40% difference can't be just due to users with disabled JS or to JS errors. Or can it?

How to find out our rate of “lost” visits, visitors or hits?

What is the industry accepted rate of lost traffic?

Answer (score 1):

I would compare a snapshot with your apache server logs, as a starting point.

I generally see some tracking loss, but it's within 5%, as far as I can tell.

Obviously 40% would render google analytics mostly useless.  Perhaps your site has some blocking js error that is breaking the analytics in some browser.  I'd start with chrome and move from there.

Comment: I tried to do this, but the way Google and Apache (or AWStats) count _page views_ is very different. Maybe it's worth checking hits to the home page only. I'll dig some more. Thanks.

Comment: From checking our logs, I realized that our AWStats setup was missing the robots. My bad. #fail

Answer (score 0):

From checking our logs, I realized that AWStats was misconfigured and was ignoring the robot crawlers. This explains a lot of things.

Comment: Usually it's the opposite, awstats blocks/filters less.